# How to get random posts and order them by date

Tags: wp-query

I need to get some random posts and order them by date.

To get random posts I used the following:

```
$query = new WP_Query(
    [
      'post__in' => $post_id_array,
      'posts_per_page' => $number,
      'orderby' => 'rand'
    ]
  );
```

To order by date I tried this:

```
'orderby' => ['rand' => 'ASC', 'date' => 'DESC']
```

But it does not work correctly. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, that will never work.  'rand' is a random order, so you always end up with a randomized order, no matter what you put for the date.

In order to do something like what you're describing, you have to use `'orderby'=>'rand'`. Then you can sort the result by date.

```
$query = new WP_Query(
    [
        'post__in' => $post_id_array,
        'posts_per_page' => $number,
        'orderby' => 'rand'
    ]
);

// Sort the resulting posts array by date
usort( $query->posts, function( $a, $b ) {
    $t1 = strtotime( $a->post_date );
    $t2 = strtotime( $b->post_date );
    return $t1 - $t2;
});

// $query->posts is now sorted and in order by date.
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. But i know about this possibility. I thought there is solution in WordPress in WP_Query class.

Answer (score 2):

First sort your posts randomly. Then, in outer query, sort the posts from subquery by date.

I would do it with the help of filters [`posts_request`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_request) and [`posts_orderby`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_orderby). The query will be modified only after setting the `'ord_rand_then_date' => true` parameter.

```
add_filter('posts_request', 'se354396_request', 50, 2);
add_filter('posts_orderby', 'se354396_orderby', 50, 2);

function se354396_request( $sql_request, $wp_query )
{
    if ( ! $wp_query->get('ord_rand_then_date', false) )
        return $sql_request;

    $sql_request = 'SELECT sub.* FROM (' . $sql_request . ') sub ORDER BY post_date DESC';
    return $sql_request;
}
function se354396_orderby( $orderby, $wp_query ) 
{ 
    $custom_order = $wp_query->get('ord_rand_then_date', false);
    if ( $custom_order !== true && $custom_order != '1' )
        return $orderby;

    return 'RAND()'; 
}
```

**Example:**

```
$my_posts = get_posts( [
    'ord_rand_then_date' => true,
    'suppress_filters'   => false,
    // other parameters
] );
```